# Good online resources for teaching students how to write a research paper

Tags: teaching, online-resource

What is a good online resource for a student who doesn't know how to write a research paper?  Content I would like to see included in such a resource: how to use library databases, what a thesis statement is, how to distinguish reliable online sources from unreliable ones, how to write a bibliography, how to cite sources in the body of the paper, etc.

The target audience would be first-year undergraduates, although to be honest something written for K-12 students (particularly middle school and high school) would probably be very useful, too.

**Edited to clarify:**  I do not mean "research paper" in the sense of "original research", but rather "Find sources about topic X in the library or online and write about them." This is a fairly common type of assignment for undergraduates (and, for that matter, high school students) in the United States in, for example, the social sciences and the humanities.

Comment: Do you distinguish between STEM and Humanities?

Comment: @svavil The kind of paper I have in mind seems (in my experience) to be more commonly assigned in the social sciences and the humanities, but if there are good resources designed for STEM students I would be happy to see them.

Answer (score 0):

First-year undergraduates are rarely taught to write research papers; in my experience, the skill set you look for is taught to Master's students and PhD students. Look for self-help books intended for PhD students. To name a few,

- Umberto Eco's [How to Write a Thesis](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/how-write-thesis) is a brilliant insight into the subject, dealing with questions such as "I am a student of *some obscure subject* in *some distant town in the middle of nowhere*, how do I start?".
- [How to write consistently boring literature](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.0030-1299.2007.15674.x/abstract) by Kay Sand-Jensen is more of a style guide and a check list, but it's definitely a valuable extra reading.
- [The Unwritten Rules of PhD Research](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Unwritten-Research-Education-Humanities-Sciences/dp/0335237029) by Marian Petre and Gordon Rugg walks aspiring PhD students through every aspect of their new lives, from working with a supervisor to writing all sorts of articles to delivering a viva.

Please make use of resources in these answers: [Learn to write scientific papers in medicine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63098/learn-to-write-scientific-papers-in-medicine/63133), [Are there resources for learning how to write a scientific paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19499/are-there-resources-for-learning-how-to-write-a-scientific-paper)

Comment: I do not mean "research paper" in the sense of "original research", but rather "Find sources about topic X in the library or online and write about them."  This is routine for undergraduates in the United States in, for example, the social sciences and the humanities.